# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello I am working on a project that if you click on a combination that a result comes out but when I press the button I look this error

[error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwAhq.png)

the error is on line 9 but unfortunately I can not figure it out and I also say that there is an error in error in the jquery.js but it leaves it externally

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs;
var left, opacity, scale;
var animating;
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    next_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    previous_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})



var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var man = $("man");
var vrouw = $("vrouw");
var kind = $("kind");
var volwassen = $("volwassen");
var vijfzestig = $("vijfzestig");
var acne = $("acne");
var grove = $("grove");
var drogehuid = $("drogehuid");
var beste = $("beste");
var make = $("make");
var jaer = $("jaer");
var neeer = $("neeer");
var hoofd = $("hoofd");
var romp = $("romp");
var benen = $("benen");

var mixColours = function mixColours() {

    if (man.checked && kind.checked && acne.checked && jaer.checked && hoofd.checked ) {
        $("colourResult").innerHTML = "ttttt";
    } else if (man.checked && volwassen.checked && acne.checked && jaer.checked && hoofd.checked) {
        $("colourResult").innerHTML = "rood wit zc";
    } else if (man.checked && vijfzestig.checked && acne.checked && jaer.checked && hoofd.checked) {
        $("colourResult").innerHTML = "rood paars zv";
    }

    if (vrouw.checked && kind.checked) {
        $("colourResult").innerHTML = "You made Yellow!";
    } else if (vrouw.checked && volwassen.checked) {
        $("colourResult").innerHTML = "You made Light Yellow!";
    }

};
window.onload = function () {
    $("mixColours").onclick = mixColours;
};
```

there is a piece that the buttons change the fieldset and there is an animation and the other that calculates what suits you best

if there are any questions about exactly what the code is, then I would like to hear it

thank you in advance

Comment: The error says that `$(this)` in `current_fs = $(this).parent();` returns `null`, but jQuery won't ever return `null`.

Comment: can u please provide html part?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Leckpn5q/ this my code

Comment: **(1)** Click on the *mix.js:9*, and post a screenshot of the line in the file where DevTools takes you. **(2)** Post the code from line 9, apart from this block of code you posted. It says the error is on line 9, so what code is on line 9? (BTW, the two mentions of 'errors' in jquery.js aren't errors in the jquery-file, it just means something went wrong while trying to execute those two lines. The error originates on line 9 of mix.js, and causes a ripple effect in jquery.js, because on that line you are referencing some jquery-function.)